# Is it possible to call the columns of the table1 in table3, going from 2nd table

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to call `firstname` and `lastname` on table 3 without using the `table 1` id but going through `table 2`. Is it possible? i want to avoid repeating table 1 id in table 3. I am not sure if this make sense.

UPDATE: i had a small change, the third table has its own column which has to display as well.

```
table 1
+----+-----------+----------+-----+
| id | firstname | lastname | age |
+----+-----------+----------+-----+
|  1 | john      | doe      |  32 |
|  2 | susy      | mathew   |  26 |
+----+-----------+----------+-----+

table 2
+----+----------+----------------+
| id | table1id | anothertableid |
+----+----------+----------------+
|  1 |        2 |             23 |
|  2 |        1 |             42 |
+----+----------+----------------+

table 3
+----+---------+----------+
| id | term2id | location |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |       1 | china    |
|  2 |       2 | tokyo    |
+----+---------+----------+
```

Comment: what you have tried so far? pls show your code

Comment: Yes this is possible. That are relations in a "relational database", the database can even check the integrity for that if you design it so. I strongly suggest you start with a SQL primer to start reading about the terms that are used in that area of information technology. SQL is a common, mature and popular language to query relational database systems.

Comment: Something like this `SELECT t1.firstname, t1.lastname FROM table3 t3 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t3.table2id = t2.id RIGHT JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.table1id = t3.table2id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help! I solved the issue using `AND`.

```
SELECT t1.firstname, t1.lastname, t3.location
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
WHERE t3.table2id = t2.id
AND t2.table1id = t1.id
```